# Native Maps App breakdown

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, android-fragments, material-design

I was wondering on how to make a similar layout and behavior like in the native Google Maps app. Please refer to the proceeding images.

Fig. 1
[image: Place information]
Is this a fragment? Is it using material library?

Fig. 2
[image: More information]
If the first one is a fragment, does this one is the same fragment when clicked?

Fig. 3
[image: More information, when sliding down]
Does this one uses the collapsing toolbar of material library?

Hopefully, someone will enlighten me about this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need collapsing toolbar layout: https://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/ it's not any magic

Comment: Was it a collapsing toolbar?  Not fragment with fancy animations?

Comment: Toolbar is toolbar, I don't know what do you mean

Comment: Thank you kind sir for mentioning toolbar. ☺

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it working using android's `BottomSheet` for the figures 1 and 2. With the help of @user1209216, I've managed to satisty the 3rd figure's question. Also you need to use the design support library.

[BottomSheet reference](https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-sheet-behavior/)

[Collapsing Toolbar reference](https://material.io/develop/android/components/collapsing-toolbar-layout/)